# Block Ownership in Mining Pool

Tags: ether, reward

It's my understanding that the block reward in Ethereum is 3 ETH, the uncle reward, and "ownership" of the bock. As the block owner, you keep the gas fees for any transactions that you include in your block. Is that correct? If so, how does block ownership work when mining in a pool? Which miner gets to own the mined block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a mining pool, you submit your proofs of hashing to the pool operator, and when a block is found, you receive a proportional reward relative to the hashes that you contributed.

Say you contributed 10 hashes, and the entire pool contributed 100 hashes, and your pool found a block. Then you would receive 3 ether * (10/100) = 0.1 ether as your reward for participating.

I hope this clears things up!

Comment: I understand that part, but afaik that's only 1/3 of the rewards for a block. I thought when you mined a block you get "ownership" of the block, and get paid the gas fees for any transactions you include in the block. The question then is who gets ownership when mining in a pool?

Comment: Same thing. The gas rewards will get paid out in the same proportion as the blocks are. All received ether from mining a block is (uncle inclusion rewards, etc. )

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there a record of ownership percentage for blocks (I'm using ethermine)? Does the pool accumulate the gas fees and pay them out at some threshold? Does the pool control the voting power of which transactions are included in the block (and control the gas price?)
  

I know that's a lot of questions, thanks for your help!

Comment: Like a record of _your_ ownership of a block that is mined by ethermine? I’m not sure if this specific pool keeps a public log of this, but they definitely have a private log. The pool accumulates all the rewards that are earned and pays them out per user at some threshold. The rest of the questions I’m not sure of, I’m not a miner, but I would assume ethermine has an FAQ or something

Comment: Right, I'm thinking of accountability. How do you know you're getting your fair share of the gas fee? It seems like owning a part share for all time in an apartment building, you would want a record of how much of the building you own to collect your rent fees. It seems like it would be good to store this information on the blockchain? I did check around for a FAQ but couldn't find anything substantial. :(

Comment: There is a very large amount of trust involved with pool based mining. I would say that if you have sufficient hash power to grab a block once every month or so, I would recommend solo mining, especially if you are doing it as a hobby. Then YOU are the miner of the blocks and you get to keep all the rewards without giving a cut to the pool. When you mine a block it’s literally like hitting a jackpot rather than consistently getting 0.003 ether payouts. Back in the day I used to solo mine and it was very rewarding